# Fundamentally doing something wrong with function calls. Functions do work in the console

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

This is a solid, proper syntax set of functions, and for the life of me I can't figure out why, but the function ServiceHover() will not run unless I trigger it manually in the console, while it's almost exact equal CategoryHover() runs perfectly each time. It has to be something about the way that I'm calling the functions, and clearly there's something about functions that I fundamentally missed in javascript, because this happens to me often, where I'm unsure why my functions are not executing.

**I keep my code all very well commented, so I shouldn't have to explain the functions's purposes, and furthermore, this is more a question of the fundamental execution of the functions rather than their inner functionality. Each function does work if called manually in the console.**

```
//this function generates the content of the page based on which category the user selects,
//which services the user selects, and help maneuver through each stage of the feature selection
//so that the QuoteEngine function can display the user's selected hour count, price per hour
// and total cost of the needed service so that the user can see very clearly what services 
//he is getting and where every dollar of his total cost is coming from so that the user can 
//make a well informed purchase decision, and be able to clearly understand the services offered
//and related pricing. 
$(document).ready(function () {

    function BasicDropdown() {
        //hide the drop-downs to begin with
        //hide element with class dropdown-category
        $(".dropdown-category").hide();
        //hide element with class dropdown-service
        $(".dropdown-service").hide();

        //when the category list title is hovered over, show the category drop-down list
        //when element with class category is hovered, do this:
        $(".category").hover(function () {
            //show the list
            $(".dropdown-category").show();
            //when element with class category is no longer hovered, do this:
        }, function () {
            //hide the list
            $(".dropdown-category").hide();
        });

        //when the service list title is hovered over, show the service drop-down list
        //when element with class service is hovered, do this:
        $(".service").hover(function () {
            //show the list
            $(".dropdown-service").show();
            //when element with class service is no longer hovered, do this:
        }, function () {
            //hide the list
            $(".dropdown-service").hide();
        });
    }

    //change the selected service based on an id input
    //create a function to change the selected service
    function ChangeService(id) {
        //clear the service list element
        $(".dropdown-service").empty();
        //make the name inside the service drop-down title show the new title
        $("#ServiceOutput").text(ServiceArray[id][0][1]);
        //loop through the chosen section of the service array for as many times as the 
        //section is in length
        for (var i = 0; i < ServiceArray[id].length; i++) {
            //each loop, append a paragraph element with a data key equal to the current
            //loop count, an id equal to the id of the array area based on the loop count,
            //and also insert the element's text according to that loop count also. 
            $(".dropdown-service").append('<p data-key="' + i + '" id="' + ServiceArray[id][i][0] + '">' + ServiceArray[id][i][1] + "</p>");
        }
        //set the variable "Category" to be equal to the chosen id. 
        Category = id;
    }

    function CategoryHover() {
        //make the category drop-down list open and show its list of services
        //when the user hovers over an element in the category drop-down, do this:
        $(".dropdown-category > p").hover(function () {
            //hide the welcome wrapper
            $(".welcomeWrapper").hide();
            //set the variable "thisKey" based on the value of the data "key" attached 
            thisKey = $(this).data("key");
            //create a variable "outputList" and assign a value to it from "CategoryArray"
            outputList = CategoryArray[thisKey];
            //set the title of the category drop-down lists title to the currently hovered text
            $("#CategoryOutput").text($(this).text());
            //call the ChangeService function and pass the variable "thisKey" into it
            ChangeService(thisKey);
            //show the service drop-down list
            $(".dropdown-service").show();
            //show the ListOutput element (this shows a short description of the hovered element)
            $(".ListOutput").show();
            //append the variable "outputList" as the value of a paragraph element
            $(".ListOutput").append('<p>' + outputList + '</p>');
        }, function () {
            //hide the service drop-down list
            $(".dropdown-service").hide();
            //empty the ListOutput element
            $(".ListOutput").empty();
            //hide the ListOutput element
            $(".ListOutput").hide();
            //show the welcome wrapper again
            $(".welcomeWrapper").show();
        });
    }

    function ServiceHover() {
        //make the service drop-down  list open and show the list of services for the category
        //when the user hovers over an element in the service drop-down, do this:
        $(".dropdown-service > p").hover(function () {
            //hide the welcome wrapper
            $(".welcomeWrapper").hide();
            //set the variable "thisKey" based on the value of the data "key" attached
            thisKey = $(this).data("key");
            //create a variable "outputList" and assign a value to it from "CategoryArray"
            outputList = ServiceArray[Category][thisKey][2][0];
            //show the ListOutput element (this shows a short description of the hovered element)
            $(".ListOutput").show();
            //append the variable "outputList" as the value of a paragraph element
            $(".ListOutput").append('<p class="blue">' + outputList + '</p>');
        }, function () {
            //empty the ListOutput element
            $(".ListOutput").empty();
            //hide the ListOutput element
            $(".ListOutput").hide();
            //show the welcome wrapper again
            $(".welcomeWrapper").show();
        });
    }

    BasicDropdown();
    CategoryHover();
    ServiceHover();

    //initiate
    ChangeService(0);

});
```

**What am I doing wrong with these calls?**

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/gbJcg/4/

**Note:** *I mentioned in my question but for some reason the update didn't show up, that all of the arrays should be assumed defined. I'll now include them to remove confusion, but it will make the scripts extensively long*

**Added detail:** *ChangeCategory works. ChangeService doesn't appear to. If I copy and paste ChangeService, however, in the console, and call it, in the console, the functionality works perfectly. Does that help? I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here...*

Comment: can you put this code in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Sure, will do right away

Comment: It'd be good to see the relevant HTML too.

Comment: For starters use `var` to declare your local variables to be local (like `thisKey` and `outputList`), not implicit globals.

Comment: @jfriend00 I messed with those tinkering with my problem, making them global. I will take note of that though. No direct connection with the problem here though, I think?

Comment: Please put your html in the fiddle as well. Otherwise we get Uncaught ReferenceError: ServiceArray is not defined  in the fiddle

Comment: Yes, definitely declare "thisKey" and "outputList" to be local variables in both those functions.

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: ServiceArray is not defined`

Comment: I just did so, they are now local variables. And @LuckySoni I mentioned in my question but for some reason the update didn't show up, that all of the arrays should be assumed defined. I'll now include them to remove confusion, but it will make the scripts extensively long.

Comment: The point of a jsFiddle is to make something that is runnable/debuggable that you can share with us so we can look at real code and figure out what's wrong.  It's of no additional use if it's just a copy of the code you already posted here.

Comment: If the arrays aren't defined, the fiddle can't work, and so it'll be pretty hard to use it to diagnose the problem.  Also - you say, "ServiceHover will not run" - how do you know this?  Have you added `console.log()` statements to check that assumption?

Comment: avoid using funtion inside document.ready.. at some point you endup with scoping issue.. actaully you can have all those hover function call inside document.ready rather inside some extra function

Comment: @bipen I did that later, fiddling with the problem, originally, they were all raw, without the holding functions.

Comment: JSFiddle updated with the arrays and variables

Comment: can u add your HTML too,  in fiddle... so that we can work it out.. see what actaully is happening

Comment: Ok, yeah it'll take a second. I thought the problem would be obvious, that's why I neglected the HTML

Comment: Here you guys go http://jsfiddle.net/gbJcg/4/

Comment: "well documented".. I think the amount of comments is over the top and reached a distracting level. For example `$(".someClass").hide();` is self explanatory, the comment should only explain why you hide it. Comments like "sets variable x to value y" have absolutly no value in my opinion and make everything hard to read.

Comment: @kapep I understand, I did that in frustration when I could not figure out some problems in the script. I tore my script apart and procedurally put it back together, commenting every line determined not to miss the issue.

Comment: @jt0dd At least you _are_ commenting your code somehow, which is a good start :) I figured it was probably for learning purposes and if it helps you then of course do it like this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well what I know is, since your `dropdown-service` is added dynamically, you need to delegated it to closest static parent present in the document which is `dropdown-service` in your case.

```
 $(".dropdown-service").on("mouseenter" ,"p",function () {
     ..
 });

  $(".dropdown-service").on("mouseleave" ,"p",function () {
      ...
 });
```

Since live is deprecated in latest version of jQuery you need to use `on` delegated event and break the hover into `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` function.

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/gbJcg/5/)

Comment: Ah, that fixes it.. But that's weird to me.. Could you understand the logic there?

Comment: What I don't understand is that the way I see it, the logic there should work.. Meh. I'm just glad it's fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Ooh, I think, maybe I see. Yes, aha! Ok, so because the list is generated dynamically, it isn't attached to the .dropdown-service > p handling function, so we need to specify them differently. Hopefully I have that right at this point..

Comment: hmm.. sorry for late... but yes you are somewhat right...since content and element  `dropdown-service > p` is added dynamically (depends on the content you choose in category).. that element is actually not present in the document in ready state. so any event event (not just hover, like click ,change ) attached to it needs to be delegated to its closest static parent.. which i am doing it with `on` event and delegating it to `.dropdown-service ` div which is present in the document when it is ready... read more about on delegated events.. which make it easier to understand..

Comment: I did have one problem here. 

    var thisKey = $(this).data("key");

I attached data keys to each element to determine which list item to display when the element is hovered (the data is used as an array key), but with this issue we had with the dynamic input and the elements not being linked to the selector normally anymore, I'm not sure how to select the data from the element currently hovered.

Comment: same `$(this).data("key");` inside the mouseenter function  should work.. where `$(this)` represent the currently hovered element

Answer (score 0):

Check your console, you have `Uncaught ReferenceError: ServiceArray is not defined`

This Exception is thrown and the rest of the program is not ran

**EDIT**: after fiddle changed with the missing Arrays initialization is seems like the code works. I added alerts in the begining of 2 functions to make sure they are called (see http://jsfiddle.net/gbJcg/3/)

**EDIT #2**:

The call to `$(".dropdown-service > p").hover(...)` is done when you do not have any elements that respond to `".dropdown-service > p"` selector, They are probably added later via ajax or some other html manipulation that is done by js

You should use the equivalent for jquery live instead:

```
$(document).on("mouseenter",".dropdown-service > p",function() {
    ....
});
$(document).on("mouseleave",".dropdown-service > p",function() {
    ....
});
```

Comment: I mentioned in my question but for some reason the update didn't show up, that all of the arrays should be assumed defined. I'll now include them to remove confusion, but it will make the scripts extensively long

Comment: Sure, just update your jsfiddle, no need for the question to be changed

Comment: Seen it, it seems that in my browsers the functions get called, how do you determine that they do not?

Comment: In the page, the two functions Category Hover and Service Hover do pretty much the same thing, Category hover makes the Service hover drop-down opens up, and the service drop-down list changes to whichever corresponding category list item is being hovered. The two functions also both call (every element has an attachment string) a piece of the function that causes a specific message to pop up at a different part of the screen. ServiceHover does not do it, CategoryHover does. However, if I copy and paste the function into my console and then call it through the console, it works, perfectly.

Comment: it might help you to look at www.evisiion.com - breaking some rules there, but I seem to wasting your time by not being able to explain my issue properly.

Comment: Found the issue,  check out Edit#2

Comment: Ah you and bipen both found it. I understand now. The function happens, but the same function also generates the thing that should be affected. The other function does it too, but I'm not sure why it works anyway,