# Event delegation - dynamically generated content

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-delegation

Because I'm generating my content dynamically, and it doesn't exists in the document until the scripts execute, normal element selectors don't apply.

```
<div class="list">
    //generated elements within here
    <p data-key="0" >List Item 1</p>
    <p data-key="1">List Item 2</p>
    //generated elements within here
</div>
```

**So this does not work(note this is the same idea as above just with different names):**

```
Category = 0;

$(".list > p").click(function(){
    var thisKey = $(this).data("key");
    for (var i = 0; i < ServiceArray[Category][thisKey][2][1][1].length; i++) {

        var listId = ServiceArray[Category][thisKey][2][1][i][2];
        var listTitle = ServiceArray[Category][thisKey][2][1][i][0];
        var List = "";

        for (var x = 0; x < ServiceArray[Category][thisKey][2][1][i][2].length; x++) {
            var Time = ServiceArray[Category][thisKey][2][1][i][2][x][3];
            var Content = ServiceArray[Category][thisKey][2][1][i][2][x][0];
            var Hours = ServiceArray[Category][thisKey][2][1][i][2][x][4];
            List += '<div class="li"><div class="selection"></div><p data-time="' + Time + '">' + Content + '<span class="orange"> ('+ Hours +'Hrs)</span></p></div>';
        }

        $(".layer4").append('<div id="' + listId + '" class="listContainer"><h2>' + listTitle + '</h2><div class="ListWrapper">' + List + '</div></div>');
    }
});
```

**Instead, I have to use**

```
$(".dropdown-service").on("click" ,"p",function () {
    //all the stuff up there, in here, except in here, I can't use $(this).data("key") to get my array keys.
});
```

**So how can I select the elements to use their attached data in the function?**

*Remember, $(".list > p") won't successfully select the element, since it was not generated until after the document loaded. I don't fully understand this yet, but in a previous question, it was explained as being the issue; this is a secondary issue, that arose from that question's solution.*

[Here is that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20455987/fundamentally-doing-something-wrong-with-function-calls-functions-do-work-in-th/20456675?noredirect=1#comment30566917_20456675).

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gbJcg/6/).

Comment: A variable to replace the `ServiceArray[Category][thisKey][2][1]` would really do wonders for your code readability.

Comment: if `dropdown-service` is an ancestor of  `.list > p` then `$(".dropdown-service").on("click" ,".list > p",function () {..});` should work

Comment: Did you try using `this` in the bottom event handler, as it should reference the `p` element and do exactly what you say it doesn't

Comment: Sorry about the readability @BlueSkies - I'll be more careful with that.

Comment: also in the fiddle there are lot of code... can you place only the relevant code there

Comment: also I can see you are adding a click handler within another `$(".dropdown-service > p").click(function () {..})` within `$(".dropdown-category > p").click(function () {..});` it is a bad idea

Comment: @ArunPJohny Sorry, it's not a child, I just edited the question a bit, mentioning that the second example is the same idea as the first one, but with names from my actual script. The first one I made simple.

Comment: Maybe `$(this).data(...)` doesn't work because there is no data attached to the newly created elements? I really don't know want to go through all that code...

Comment: can you atleast point us to the function that is creating the `p` elements and where the `data` is assigned to it

Comment: @FelixKling Of course, I don't expect you to, I just added it so no one would ask. The problem is basic, I can't use 


    `$(parent > p).click(function(){
        var dataKey = $(this).data("key");
    });`

on my list because the list was generated dynamically. So I have to use 


    `$(".dropdown-service").on("click" ,"p",function () {
        var dataKey = $(this).data("key");
    });`


The only problem there is that I have no idea how to use that method  to get the dataKey from the clicked element's attached data.

Comment: Again, you'd do it exactly as you have written, as the paragraph is the context of the handler, you'd do `$(this).data('key')`, as long as the element has any data to get.

Comment: @ArunPJohny line 630 `ChangeService();` generates it

Comment: You don't have to change the body of the event handler to make it work with event delegation. You cannot bind the handler to the element because it doesn't exist yet. Event delegation solves this by attaching the event handler to an ancestor instead. However, when the handler is *executed*, i.e. one of the elements was clicked, then obviously the element must exist (otherwise it cannot be clicked). That's why `$(this).data('key')` should work and if it doesn't, the problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: @adeneo I can't do that, because only the parent is selected in `$(".dropdown-service").on("click" ,"p",function () { var dataKey = $(this).data("key"); });` while the data is actually attached to the p elements within it.

Comment: No. `this` refers to the `p` element. jQuery makes sure of that: *"When jQuery calls a handler, the `this` keyword is a reference to the element where the event is being delivered; for directly bound events this is the element where the event was attached and for delegated events this is an element matching `selector`."* http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: You're not really getting how the delegated event handler works, it sets `this` to the element in the selector after the event, in this case `p`, and not `.dropdown-service`, so `this` will be the `p` element

Comment: @FelixKling Right, but $(this) is talking about $(".dropdown-service") and no longer $(".dropdown-service > p") where the data is located. There's no data on $(".dropdown-service") itself. So, are you saying that I can use, inside, $(".dropdown-service > p") as the selector? Since I selected the parent element for event delegation, does the child element suddenly now work with it's usual selector?

Comment: Please read my previous comments.

Comment: Ahh, ok. Yes, I'm misunderstanding then.. Hmm. Well, I don't know then.

Comment: That's why I'm saying the problem/error must be somewhere else, if `$(this).data(...)` doesn't work for you.

Comment: Ok, I'll look more into it, and post a better question if I need to.

Comment: seems to be working fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PYAAf/1/ click on the dropdown and check the console

Comment: Just so I understand, have you actually tried the suggestions given above to use `$(this).data("key");`?

Comment: Yes, it does appear to be elsewhere.. An unusual issue here. Sorry.

Comment: @BlueSkies Yes, that's what I'm doing, the issue seems to be something else in my script.

Comment: @jt0dd so can we assume the issue is resolved.... for further question create a fiddle which reproduces your exact issue... don't create one with all your code from the page

Comment: My apologies, I was told before that I should include everything, which didn't quite make sense, but anyway, will provide simplified examples from now on. I did pinpoint my problem, can you look at this? `$(".dropdown-service").on("click" ,"p",function () {
   $(".welcomeWrapper").hide();
  });` line 700 JS Fiddle. That one line refuses to run, even alone like that.

Comment: `$(".welcomeWrapper").hide();` I mean, refuses to run. More clearly, It doesn't run when called by the function. If I call it manually, it works.